# How to shorten the expression of "not contain multi strings" in every contain conditions . regex R

Tags: r, regex

I have to detect strings contain multi pattern of words but cannot contain multi pattern of words as well

**Data :**

```
tt <- c("apple","banana","orange","appleZ","appleX","bananaZ","orangeY")
```

**Goal :**
grep only without Z,X,Y

```
[1]  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
```

**Problem :**
the scripts too long to repeating `(?![X|Y|Z])` in every contain patterns

```
stri_detect_regex(tt,"apple(?![X|Y|Z])|banana(?![X|Y|Z])|orange(?![X|Y|Z])")
```

Do we have any other beautiful way to simplify the script ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use non capturing group

```
(?:apple|banana|orange)(?![XYZ])
```

[`Regex Demo`](https://regex101.com/r/EelehH/2)

P.S:- If you meant to match `|` then only `|` inside `[] ( character class )` makes sense, even then no need to repeat them, if you meant to use it for alternation then you don't need `|` inside `[] ( character class )`

Comment: yes , i meant to | for alternation . Your answer solve more problems in my script .Perfect.

Answer (score 3):

You could use `grepl`

```
grepl('^[^XYZ]+$', tt)
#[1]  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
```

This returns TRUE if none of `X`, `Y` or `Z` is present anywhere in the string.